# In Highcharts, how can we separatedly set up the border color of each block in a Pyramid chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I'm wondering if there are any ways to separately set up border color of each block in a Pyramid chart using Highcharts.

Here is what I wanted:
[image]

As you can see, border color of each block is different

But in Highcharts what I got is just 1 color for all:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/18009rf1/

```
series: [{
  name: 'Unique users',
  borderColor: "#333333",
  data: [
    ['Website visits', 15654],
    ['Downloads', 4064],
    ['Requested price list', 1987],
    ['Invoice sent', 976],
    ['Finalized', 846]
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also provide an Object inside the `data`-Array with custom properties just for this specific slice of data. For your example:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Unique users',
  borderColor: '#000000',
  data: [
    {name: 'Website visits', y: 15654, borderColor: "#FF0000"},
    {name: 'Downloads', y: 4064, borderColor: '#00FF00'},
    ['Requested price list', 1987],
    ['Invoice sent', 976],
    ['Finalized', 846]
  ]
}]
```

Here we have a default borderColor of `#000000` and custom ones for the first and second slice. You can of course leave out the default one and provide a custom one for each data object. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/18009rf1/3/

Comment: Greate answer! This is what I needed. Just wonder why these properties are not listed in Highcharts' API reference. Thanks Martin.